# Where do I import setConfig form in workbox v5?

Tags: workbox

In workbox v4 it was easy: `workbox.setConfig({ debug: false });`

Where do I import `setConfig` in v5 from? The docs are not there yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the CDN version of Workbox v5, then `workbox.setConfig({debug: false})` works the same way as it previously did. (But I'm assuming you wouldn't have asked this if you were using the CDN version.)

We expect that most folks will use Workbox v5 not via the CDN, but instead by consuming the JavaScript modules and creating their own bundled service workers. In that setup, toggling between `dev` and `prod` mode is different.

The Workbox codebase uses the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable to determine whether it's in `dev` or `prod` mode, with `if` statements [like these](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/ecc18673aab127c532168e4dafee65f6e47931b1/packages/workbox-routing/src/Router.ts#L111-L113) that will conditionally log found throughout the code.

If you're using `webpack` to create a bundled service worker that uses the Workbox JavaScript modules, then `process.env.NODE_ENV` will be automatically replaced with the value of your [configured `mode`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/). That means that everything should "just work" and you'll get a bundle with extra logging statements when `webpack` is configured to be in a development mode, and a smaller bundle without logging when `webpack` is in production mode.

If you're using Rollup or another bundler to consume the Workbox JavaScript modules, you'll need to add in a plugin (like [`@rollup/replace`](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/replace)) that will replace `process.env.NODE_ENV` with a string based on whether you want to create a `dev` or `prod` bundle.

Under the hood, if you're using the `generateSW` mode in Workbox v5, we use Rollup to create the final bundled service worker. You can take a look at how we handle the string replacement in the [`workbox-build` source code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/ecc18673aab127c532168e4dafee65f6e47931b1/packages/workbox-build/src/lib/bundle.js#L37).